# Loop through the array that was passed into he method. Display the values in the array?

Tags: java, arrays, methods

I'm brand new to Java, and I'm working on a project for school. I have a basic understanding of arrays, but am confused by an instruction and could use some guidance. Here are the instructions for the beginning of the assignment:

1.) Start a program in a class named ArrayPrinter. Ignore the main method for a moment.

2.) In your class, create a static method named printArray with one parameter of type int[] named arr. Inside this method, do the following.

a. Keep all of your output on one line using System.out.print() until directed to use println().

b. Display an opening square bracket character.

c. Loop through the array that was passed into the method. Display the values in the array. Add a comma and a space after every value except for the last one.

d. Using System.out.println(), display a closing square bracket character.

2C is where I am confused. I don't really understand the question. Any and all help or advice would be appreciated. Here is what I've got so far:

```
public class arrayPrinterMain {
public static void main(String[] args) {

}
public static void printArray(int[] arr) {
    System.out.print("[");
}
}
```

Comment: Not exactly sure what part of 2C you're struggling with. Use a for loop. Array elements can be accessed via the `[]` operator. [This tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html) might help.

Comment: Also, you could use this code: `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));`

Comment: @Everv0id The instruction is: "loop through the array..."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> public static void printArray(int[] arr) {
>
> ```
>     int size = arr.length;
>     System.out.print("[");
>     for(int i=0;i< size; i++){
>         System.out.print(arr[i]);
>         if(i<size-1){
>             System.out.print(",");
>         }
>     }
>     System.out.println("]");
> }
> ```

Arrays.toString(arr) will be better usually but your question says "loop through array".

Comment: Thank you! This was really helpful. I think I need to do a little more research on for loops...

Answer (score 0):

use an enhanced for loop its neat

```
  for(int i:anArray){System.out.print(i);}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Public static void methodname(int[] arr){
    System.out.println("[");

    for(int i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
        System.out.print(arr[i]];
        if(i<arr.length-1)
            System.out.print(",");
    }

    System.out.println("]");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code you need is:

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
builder.append('[');
for (int x : arr) {
    builder.append(x).append(',');
}
System.out.println(builder.append(']').toString());
```